# jQuery Forms Plugin AjaxSubmit "destroys" the response in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer

I am using the Jquery Forms Plugin to handle uploads in my asp.net MVC application. The upload itself works fine, but the success callback function, which actually receives a HTML-snippet to show in a div does not receive the complete HTML.

This is my Javascript Code

```
$("#ajaxSubmit").click(function (e) {
    $("#ajaxForm").ajaxSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        url: $("#ajaxForm").attr("action"),
        success: function (r) {
            $("#contentWrap").html(r);
            alert(r);
            InitializeQuestionForm();
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $("#contentWrap").html(XMLHttpRequest + "<br />" + textStatus + "<br />" + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return e.preventDefault();
});
```

If I run this in IE the alert shows me just

```
<DIV id=ajaxContainer></DIV>
```

which is not what my controller sends. (Strange are the capitalization of the HTML, the missing quotes and of course the missing inner HTML of the DIV)

If I run it in Firefox I receive this, like it should be:

```
<div id="ajaxContainer">

    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="Das Feld &quot;QuestionId&quot; muss eine Zahl sein." data-val-required="Das Feld &quot;QuestionId&quot; ist erforderlich." id="QuestionId" name="QuestionId" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" value="true" id="CloseWindow" />
</div>
```

Somebody any idea what am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked in Fiddler or the F12 Developer Tools to ensure that your XHR is returning exactly the same response to IE?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, I checked with Fiddler and the response send to the IE is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did not find the solution for the actual problem - it is still strange. But the workaround is to return a JSON result insted of HTML, and then do something with the JSON in my javascript.